# How to create a json with >20k entries (dummy data) at run time?

Tags: json, web-sql

```
tx.executeSql("insert into Users (id, idNumber, uName) values (?,?,?)", [i,data.user[i].id, data.user[i].name],successCB,errorCB);
```

Is it possible to add multiple `rows(objects)` in JSON at runtime so that JSON can be passed to generate bulk data in single MySQL `INSERT` query?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Let's start with a basic data object:

```
let data = { user: [] }
```

Now we can just loop it 20k times, and append random data:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    data.user.push({id: i, name: makeid() })
}
```

If you need it in JSON:

```
let json_data = JSON.stringify(data)
```

Please note, this example uses `makeid()` from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/820304) on generating random strings, but you can use anything you want for that.

Comment: A good library for seeding information is [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker)